# Is there a way to a pull a report of upcoming charges in Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a Stripe account and all my customers pay me through it, I have a monthly subscription, recurring payment, everything was set up. What I need is a way to forecast or project the upcoming charges for next month based on the recurring payments or subscriptions. Stripe is not providing that report so I was wondering if there is a way to pull this data and know what to expect to get paid for the next month.

Answer (score 1):

You can export a CSV of all active subscriptions by going to https://dashboard.stripe.com/subscriptions. I then imported it into Google Sheets, filtered out the subscriptions that are canceling. I then filtered for subscriptions with a *Current Period End* of today to the end of the month. So for example: with today being June 9, I filtered for subscriptions from June 9 - June 30. What's left is my expected subscription charges for the rest of the month. "Expected" being the keyword here because any of those subscribers could cancel at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe can't provide you with a report on potential income as it's impossible to know if all your subscriptions' invoices will be paid on time.

If you want to get a rough estimate you could [list all your active subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list) and tally up the monthly amount of each Price linked to those subscriptions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can use a subscription list? Any idea. Thanks